# Removing newlines when writing to text file in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to store user messages from a textarea, into a text file, along with the user's name and date(though lets ignore the date for now).

Lets say the the user, named John, enters the following text into the textarea:

```
Hello
How are you?
```

I want the text file to store this as:

```
John#Hello\nHow are you?
```

I have tried many ways to remove/replace the newline from the textarea, but the result I get in the text file always looks like this:

```
John#Hello
How are you?
```

I just can't make it not go to the next line in the file. I've tried searching and haven't seen anyone having this problem...so perhaps I don't know what I'm doing. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: `John#Hello\nHow are you?` will always produce a new line when writing to a file with the `\n`. Are you asking to store `\n` as 2 characters? If so, use single quotes. Show your code.

Comment: do you want a literal backslash and `n` in the file?

Comment: `$var = "John#Hello\nHow are you?";` will store a new line. Do `$var = 'John#Hello\nHow are you?';` will store as a string literal.  Even harder to give a concrete answer without seeing code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To replace the newline with a literal `\n`, use `str_replace` and put `\n` in single quotes so it's not interpreted as an escape sequence.

```
$text = str_replace("\n", '\n', $text);
file_put_contents("filename.txt", "$username#$text");
```

[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Alternatively, you could escape the backslash: `"\\n"`

Comment: Wishing you well on this one. Looks good to me, but I fear the OP'll just come back and say "It doesn't work...". (I could be wrong though) Hoping for a green tick here and that you're not in for a long haul. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Barmar, that worked for me. I wasn't aware that it mattered if I used "\n" or '\n'.

Comment: I've added a link to a question that explains all the differences between single and double quoted strings.

Answer (score -1):

Use `preg_replace("#[\n\r]+#", '\\n', $text);`